# Node return yielded value from Q.async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, generator, q

With this piece of code :

```
function * foo(ctx) {
   // process some things
   // yield some async stuff...

   return 'foo';
}

Q.async(function * (ctx) {
  return yield foo(ctx);
})(this).done(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

I expected `result` to be the result of `foo()` (i.e. `'foo'`), but it is rather *the* actual generator object!

What am I missing or don't I understand here?

#### ** Solution **

While the answers are good solutions, I figured that I could even shorten the whole thing by simply doing

```
result = Q.async(foo)(this);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async` is a generator function decorator. Any function that you intend to use as a promise trampoline must be decorated. Also, I have elected to pass the `this` context as `this`.

```
var foo = Q.async(function *() {
   // yield, yield, yield
   return "foo";
});

var bar = Q.async(function *() {
    // yield, yield, yield
    return foo.call(this);
});

bar.call(this).done(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: So, if I understand you right, instead of doing `return yield foo(ctx);` I should do `return Q.async(foo)(ctx)` ? **Edit**: well, it seems to work!

Comment: What is a 'promise trampoline'?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you need to do this instead:

```
return yield* foo(ctx);
```

What you had previously was calling `return yield foo(ctx)`. That will do `foo(ctx)` to create a generator, then `yield ...` will yield the generator. Since the generator isn't a promise, Q will consider it resolved and make the `yield` result in a generator. Then the result of the `yield` is returned, so the `async` function results in a generator object.  By adding the `*`, you tell the generator to take over rather than yield, and thus the result of `yield* foo(ctx)` is actually `foo` instead of a generator returning `foo`.

The second problem I ran into locally (which you may not if you have actual async code in foo) is that if the `foo` generator is synchronous instead of asynchronous, it appears to return `foo` immediately instead of returning a promise that resolves to `foo`, so the `.done` function does not exist.

Comment: No, it does not work. I get `Object #<GeneratorFunctionPrototype> has no method 'done'`.

Comment: It turned out that you had part of the solution. I wrapped `Q.async` inside `Q(Q.async(function * () ...)).done(...)` for things to work.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. That said, what I posted totally works with the sample code you posted, so in the future perhaps a more specific example would be better.

Comment: Yes. I had to `yield *` inside my actual example, thus why I said that you had part of the solution. But Kris Kowal really got me understand with his snippet. :)